# how to bring a button to the focus in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have ScrollView  which contains 10 buttons. When a activity is launched only first four buttons is visible on the screen. How can i bring the last button to focus when activity is launched.?

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button android:text="Claim" android:id="@+id/claim"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:onClick="headerClick" android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp" android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"></Button> . (etc). .<Button android:text="Signature" android:id="@+id/signature"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:onClick="headerClick" android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
                    android:padding="10dp"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Just to make it clear for others, do you want to scroll to the bottom so the last button is visible (but not given focus), or do you want to focus on the button by highlighting/selecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(mScrollView.getWidth(), 0);
```